# Excel Advanced Filter Criteria - Starts with, does not end with

Tags: excel, criteria, advanced-filter

As a **VERY** simplified example of a huge set of rules I'm dealing with, suppose I have a range in Excel with, say, the following column:

```
Col1
ABCD
ABCE
ABCF
ABCG
BCDE
```

And I would like to create an advanced filter that says `Begins with ABC, but does not include ABCD or ABCE`.

I tried do create the advanced autofilter as follows:

```
Col1     Col1
ABC*     <>ABCD*
ABC*     <>ABCE*
```

But the first rule lets in `ABCE` and the second rule `ABCD`, so the filter does not work as I'd want.

Using a tool such as regular expressions, I could write it as `ABC[^DE]`, but I'm a bit lost if there's a way to create this with Excel and autofilters specifically.

Again, this is a very simplified example, but that is my general challenge.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these 3 functions(the criteria header must be included as blank):

[image]

E2:`=LEFT(A2,3)="ABC"`
F2:`=RIGHT(A2)<>"D"`
G2:`=RIGHT(A2)<>"E"`

Comment: Yes, a function was absolutely the way to go!! Thanks a freaking ton!!